# RegExp for numbers

Tags: regex, numbers

I want to build correct RegExp for next requirements: String must be contains only 10 numbers or 10 numbers comma 10 numbers (in second variant can be space before and after comma)... And I don't can to build this :(

My variant is this, but it isn't correct:

```
([0-9]{10})|([0-9]{10}\s*\,\s*[0-9]{10})
```

Sorry for my English =)

UPD: Thanks all for help!

Comment: `^` and `$` will match beginning and end of the string, respectively

Comment: Wow, you sure got a lot of wrong answers.  You might want to try this free RegEx builder:  Expresso: http://www.ultrapico.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your pattern is correct, but has a small defect. The rule to remember is:

> If your pattern is OR (`|`) of two other patterns, for which one of them is sub-pattern of another, put the largest pattern first.

So by reordering what you already have, we will get:

```
^([0-9]{10}\s*\,\s*[0-9]{10})$|^([0-9]{10})$
```

Added `^` and `$` to include full line matches only.

Comment: `123456789011211121211212   , sdafasdf`
is match)

Comment: This is inefficient (much longer than it needs to be) and technically not correct, because it allows *any number* of spaces around the comma, but your requirement states *one* optional space around the comma.

Comment: @Bohemian any number of spaces as better for me. Maybe my English can not express my problem... I try don't use google translate =)

Comment: Even shorter `/^\d{10}( ?, ?\d{10})?$/`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
^\d{10}( ?, ?\d{10})?$
```

Using `?` makes the preceding expression optional

Comment: I need only 10 numbers. Not no more, no less

Comment: @LuckSound I think the op does not want to match 10 numbers from the string, maybe he wants to validate the string.

Comment: I think I understand. I have added start and end anchors, which fixes the problem. This regex is the most efficient way of expressing your need (more efficient than the answer you accepted)

Comment: @Bohemian If accepted variant will not verify, and your variant is better for me then I add to you some votes =)

Answer (score 1):

Here's the regex you need:

```
\d{10}( ?, ?\d{10})?
```

Comment: Your question didn't give much context, but you could wrap the above regex in parens to group the match if you are trying to match multiple times, or add ^ and $ if you are trying to match the entire string. If you are not necessarily matching the entire string, you need to identify what chars are allowed following the 10 digits. Is it any non-digit (\D)?

Answer (score 1):

You have to match the begin and the end of the string.

```
/^\d{10}( *, *\d{10})?$/
```

Try it with:

```
/^\d{10}( *, *\d{10})?$/.test(your_string);
```

Comment: Technically this isn't what was asked. This allows any number of spaces before/after the comma and OP said only one space. Further, the question said nothing about slash characters at start/end, so this wouldn't match his pattern at all.

Comment: 1234567890 is not match =(

Comment: @LuckSound `/^\d{10}( *, *\d{10})?$/.test('1234567890');` is true.

Comment: @xdazz maybe site where I test ReqEx don't work good... I try in my project

Comment: @LuckSound You just need to test it in the console of the browser.

Answer (score 1):

```
^\d{10}(?: ?, ?\d{10})?$
```

- `^...$` = between beginning and end of the string
- `\d{10}` = 10 digits
- `?` = optional space
- `(?:)` = non=capturing group

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
(^\d{10}$|^\d{10} ?, ?\d{10}$)
```